# Understanding the association of the bilinear form and matrix associated with it

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, linear-transformations, partial-derivative, bilinear-form

From S.L Linear Algebra:

> Show that the association $A \rightarrow g_A$ is an isomorphism
>   between the space of $m \times n$ matrices, and the space of bilinear maps of  $\mathbb{K}^m \times \mathbb{K}^n$ into $\mathbb{K}$.
>
> **Note**: In calculus, if $f$ is a function of $n$ variables, one associates
>   with $f$ a matrix of second partial derivatives ($\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$), which is
>   symmetric. This matrix represents the second derivative, which is a
>   bilinear map.

$g_A$ simply implies that the bilinear map $g$  has a matrix $A$ associated with it, such that $g_A(X, Y)=X^TAY$.

## Confusion:

It is visible that $A$ is simply an arbitrary $m \times n$ matrix and $g_A$ is bilinear map $\mathbb{K}^m \times \mathbb{K}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$

Association above $A \rightarrow g_A$, can be "expanded" to $A \rightarrow \mathbb{K}^m \times \mathbb{K}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$, which makes it seem like a composite map $L: A \circ \mathbb{K}$.

Thus if we have $X \in \mathbb{K}^m$ and $Y \in \mathbb{K}^m$, then it sems like $L(X, Y)=g_A(X^TAY)=(X^TAY)^2$.

---

I'm highly confused about the definition of mapping $L$, if I'm certain that the definition that I've obtained is correct, then perhaps I could show that kernel of $L$ is trivial (showing injectivity), and then by rank nullity that map is bijective. Therefore, is the result above appropriate by any means?

Perhaps the example in the **Note** was a linear map similar to $L$ above (which is why second derivative is discussed there)?

It seems to me the **Note** is talking about specialization of hessian matrix which contains bilinear forms (second derivatives) as elements.

**In short**, what's the correct definition of association $A \rightarrow g_{A}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\to g_A$ takes an $m\times n$ matrix and maps it to the associated bilinear form. So it should be something of the form: $$L:\mathbb K^{m\times n}\to Bil_{\mathbb K}(\mathbb K^m\times \mathbb K^n) \\ A\longmapsto g_A$$ So $L(A)(X,Y)=g_A(X,Y)$.